# What is the usage of Restriction in Jena of OWL?

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, owl

If I define a owl class `A` with a `mincardinalityRestriction` (for example, at least K) of a property, does it mean I have to add at least K values to the property when I create a individual of this class `A` ? If I ignore this restriction, can the individual be created successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A reasoner does not require the assertions to be available, it just needs to know that the restriction exists.

By "created successfully" I assume you mean "the ontology is consistent". Jena (and most other APIs) will allow you to create inconsistent ontologies "successfully", as in, without any errors.

Comment: Thank you. Jena allow I to creat inconsistent ontologies without any errors, so what is the meaning of the restriction defined on a class and when does the restriction work ?

Comment: If you have a reasoner attached to the model you can ask the API whether or not the model is consistent.